# Problem submitting form not working for me

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

i need help, am trying to submit a form using jquery but its not working for me

```
<form id="form" method="post" value="" action="https://google.com">
    <input type="text" id="input">
    <input type="button" id="button" value="Submit">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $( "#button" ).click(function() {
        $( "#form" ).submit();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: *"not working"* isn't a very valuable technical problem description that gives us much of value to work with. What is or isn't happening and what are you expecting different from that?

Comment: In what way is it not working? Is it not submitted at all? Does it not redirect correctly? Do you really need to use javascript or jQuery to submit this form? Have you tried adding `type="submit"` to the submit button? If you are trying to make a Google search form you should probably prevent the form from submitting and redirect the user to `https://google.com/q=<search term>`

Comment: My bet is your only problem is not using `name` on the `<input>`. Form controls won't submit without a `name`

Comment: @FredBrown, @charlietfl is right, apart from `script` url I don't see why the code won't work! you can take out this question if you want, just use the `cdn` and you are set. <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `onclick` event.

```js
function ClickMethod() {
  document.getElementById("form").submit();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form" method="post" value="" action="https://google.com">
  <input type="text" id="input">
  <input type="button" id="btnSubmit" onclick="ClickMethod()" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: How does this explain why the code shown isn't working?

Comment: @charlietfl which code? my code or OPs code?

Comment: Th OP's code of course since they say it isn't working

Comment: Other than the input not having a name what OP is showing should work...so the issue then becomes...what exactly isn't working? Sure you can do the same process another way but that doesn't explain why the original isn't working or solve OP's question

Comment: @charlietfl apart from that, the `onclick` event too is not working!

Comment: How do you know that? No reason it shouldn't

Comment: @charlietfl what you said is correct, missed the cdn url that will resolve the issue indeed! I have asked OP to take out the question. thanks for letting me know.

Comment: OP hasn't shown source for their jQuery library so using cdn has nothing to do with their code shown. I think you are confusing being able to run it in a live demo with what is actually shown

Comment: This is OPs code where the `onclick` is not working: https://jsfiddle.net/Manju06/nfwu52c6/38/

Comment: Well of course...you didn't include jQuery library. Making a big assumption that OP didn't either without asking about errors and general debugging details

Answer (score -3):

```
<form id="form" class="anyname" method="post" value="" action="https://google.com">
    <input type="text" id="input">
    <input type="button" id="button" value="Submit">
</form>
```

after giving a class to the form you can run the following jquery

```
$('.anyname')[0].submit();
```

Comment: jQuery has a `submit()` method in the API that wraps the native submit